# Lat Lon not metres map Coordinates at mouse cursor position

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I'm using QGIS 2.14.10 LTR, my project crs is EPSG:27700 but the coordinates shown at the bottom of the QGIS window are in lat lon not metres. The odd thing is if I toggle the button to show extent instead of cursor position the figures are presented in metres. I've included a couple of screenshots.

Does anyone have any idea how I can change things to show the cursor location in metres?

[image: cursor position]

[image: extent]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The coordinates should be displaying in metres anyway. However, double check that the CRS is set as:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs
```

If that does not help, go to Project -> Project Properties and check that the Coordinate display is set to Map Units (Meters):
[image: it's the properties window]

If none of this works, you have found a bug.

Comment: Thanks, the display coordinates was set to degrees! I've marked the answer as correct :-)

Comment: No problem! I've had it happen to me a few times

Comment: A useful answer thanks! My display defaulted to degrees as well.

I upgraded to 3.2 from 2.89, where the co-ordinate display seemingly defaulted to the most relevant for the CRS - Using CRS EPSG 27700 used to default to metres, now it does not. From my perspective, that is a bug. Ideally the display should default to the system most common for that CRS, should it not?